# How to get Pull request Id in azure devops

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to extract this PR id using bash task.
[image]

Comment: You should use the predefined variable `$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values

Comment: I think we can't, becuase, this variable is initialized only if the build ran because of a Git PR affected by a branch policy.

I want to fetch this number from anywhere inside the project

Comment: That ID doesn't come from Git, so Git can't help you get it. (I don't think the [tag:bash] tag is really called-for here either, although if azure runs everything through bash, at least there are some commands you can use to see if it provides anything *to* bash in the process.)

Comment: In **what context** do you want to get this value? From what starting point? There are REST APIs you can use to query pull requests, but your question doesn't include enough specificity to help you.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Mann, We want to bypass branch policy that is minimum 1 reviewer requires for Pull Request to be completed. 

And we want to automate this step using bash task.
1. Create a PR
2. Bypass the minimum 1 reviewer required policy (By specific person, which has access to bypass policy)

We're using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest). In this link we can do stuff but to recognise the PR, we need its id. So that is the use case.

Comment: Hi MIHIR, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      curl --location --request GET 'https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>/<Project Name>/_apis/git/repositories/<repository ID>/pullrequests?searchCriteria.sourceRefName=refs/heads/<source branch name>&api-version=6.0' \
```

[image]

Rest API is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-requests/get-pull-requests?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

You can query with multiple conditions.

Use this API to get the repository ID:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering, actually I have tried different approach. I have listed all the repos and then applied filter and the extracted the *codeReviewId* from that. All this done using bash task. Also, I have tried using the API in local system, it's working for me. But in project level, we want that to be implemented using bash task.